# Генерация кода интерфейса клиента gRPC на основе *.proto | Yandex Cloud API

Tags: node.js, vue.js, grpc, яндекс-облако

Мне нужно использовать потоковое распознавание речи в своём приложении Vue с использованием Yandex Speechkit.
[Документация Яндекса](https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/speechkit/stt/streaming#examples) по этому поводу даёт в принципе хорошее представление о том, как это делается. Следуя их инструкции, я сгенерировал два файла js (в их примере использовался python, но в моём случае это, думаю, невозможно).
Вот инструкция для питона:

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc \
-I . -I third_party/googleapis \
--python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. \
yandex/cloud/ai/stt/v2/stt_service.proto
```

А вот та же инструкция для JS:

```
protoc -I . -I third_party/googleapis \
--js_out=import_style=commonjs:./out \
--grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:./out \
yandex/cloud/ai/stt/v2/stt_service.proto
```

Здесь в качестве пути указывается `./out`, потому что в ином случае файлы генерируются в самом скачанном репозитории Яндекса, то есть уже не совсем так, как написано в интрукции:

> В результате в этой директории будут созданы файлы с интерфейсом клиента: `stt_service_pb2.py` и `stt_service_pb2_grpc.py`.

В результате выполнения команды каталог `out` содержит не просто два нужных файла, а целую ветку каталогов с ними, которая дублирует путь к `stt_service.proto`:

[image: Результат выполнения команды]

В начале каждого файла содержится несколько импортов и я не понимаю, почему они тут находятся, если никаких других файлов `*_pb.js` команда не генерировала:

```
var google_api_annotations_pb = require('../../../../../google/api/annotations_pb.js')

var google_protobuf_duration_pb = require('google-protobuf/google/protobuf/duration_pb.js')

var yandex_api_operation_pb = require('../../../../../yandex/api/operation_pb.js')

var yandex_cloud_operation_operation_pb = require('../../../../../yandex/cloud/operation/operation_pb.js')
```

"Прототипы" этих файлов есть в папке репозитория Яндекса, и они так же импортируются в файле `stt_service.proto`:

```
import "google/api/annotations.proto";
import "google/protobuf/duration.proto";
import "yandex/api/operation.proto";
import "yandex/cloud/operation/operation.proto";
```

Разумеется, когда я тупо переношу нужные мне два файла в мой проект, сборщик ругается, что не может никакие модули импортировать. Более того, я проверил это для питона и он тоже ругается на то, что не может импортировать указанные модули.

Я впервые сталкиваюсь с gRPC и плохо понимаю, как это устроено. В случае, когда импортов нет (а именно такие случаи рассматриваются во всех немногочисленных туториалах по данной теме) всё просто и понятно. А тут ещё и происходит нечто совсем не то, что описано в примере Яндекса.

Буду благодарен любым советам и откликам, брутфорс гугла ни к чему не приводит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не работал с GRPC из JS, только из Golang. Судя по всему, API Yandex Speechkit использует такие типы данных, как [google.protobuf.Duration](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/duration.proto#L103) (они де-факто стали стандартными типами в мире GRPC). Другие файлы - это что-то типа общей части для облачного API Яндекса, которую надо везде включать.

Компилятор `protoc`, к сожалению, далеко не юзер-френдли инструмент. Скорее всего, вам надо в корневой папке, которая у вас обозначена `.`, назовём её `project`, воссоздать всю иерархию зависимостей вашего проекта. То есть создать папки и разместить в них файлы:

- `$HOME/project/yandex/cloud/ai/stt/v2/...`
- `$HOME/project/yandex/api/...`
- `$HOME/project/yandex/cloud/...`
- `$HOME/project/google/api/annotations.proto`
- `$HOME/project/google/protobuf/duration.proto` (под вопросом, скорее всего, этот протофайл поставляется с самим компилятором в системные пути)

Затем в команде вызова `protoc` попробуйте перечислить все файлы из `project`, а не только `yandex/cloud/ai/stt/v2/stt_service.proto`.

Это общее направление для дебага, не уверен, что этого будет достаточно для успешного решения. Надо глубже разбираться с `protoc`. У него есть ещё очень интеренсная опция `M`, которая нужна для настройки импортов между пакетами. Боюсь, что без неё не обойдётся.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ выше помог, но на случай, если у кого-то появится подобная проблема, опишу свои действия.

Я не сумел настроить правильно protoc, чтобы он генерировал и все импорты, в том числе вложенные в других proto-файлах, поэтому просто применил генерацию ко всем файлам `*.proto` в папке репозитория Яндекса:

```sh
# для папки yandex
for file in `find yandex -type f -name "*.proto"`
do
protoc $file \
-I . -I third_party/googleapis \
--js_out=import_style=commonjs:./out
done

# для папки third_party, в которой лежат google-прототипы
for file in `find third_party -type f -name "*.proto"`
do
protoc $file \
-I . -I third_party/googleapis \
--js_out=import_style=commonjs:./out
done
```

После этого переместил папки yandex и google в свой проект, в папку `api`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для тестирования, будет ли это работать, в тестовый компонент `Helloworld.vue` добавил это:

```js
const pb = require('../api/yandex/cloud/ai/stt/v2/stt_service_pb');
const pb_grpc = require('../api/yandex/cloud/ai/stt/v2/stt_service_grpc_web_pb');
console.log(pb);
console.log(pb_grpc);
```

При компилировании была ошибка импорта в одном из сгенерированных файлов, но достаточно было просто подправить путь и больше никаких проблем не было. В итоге консоль браузера вывела то, что нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Непонятно, правда, почему у них одинаковое содержание - снова несоответствие с туториалом Яндекса.

Благодарю @vitaly-isaev за справку.

Answer (score 0):

В новой версии SDK все это есть из коробки. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@yandex-cloud/nodejs-sdk

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]